# How can I be sure that it first starts with the "Startpoint" function call and waits until this one is resolved to start the next function call?

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback, axios, map-function

Within a map function, I want to call an asynchronous function if the name is "Startpoint" and the same function if the name is "Question". These functions call an API (from dialogflow). I have the problem that the second function call overtakes the first one.

How can I be sure that it first starts with the "Startpoint" function call and waits until this one is resolved to start the next function?

Here is the code:

```
const editorJSON = {1: "Startpoint", 2: "Answer", 3: "Question"};

Object.keys(editorJSON).map((key, index) => {
  if (editorJSON[key].name === "Startpoint") {
     saveNodeasIntentinDialogflow(someArgument);

  if (editorJSON[key].name === "Question") {
     saveNodeasIntentinDialogflow(someArgument);
```

And here is the function saveNodeasIntentinDialogflow (simplified):

```
const saveNodeAsIntentinDialogflow = async (someParameter) => {
    try {
  const res = await axios.post(
    `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/agent/intents:batchUpdate`)}
```

Comment: with `for .. in ` loop and await

Comment: Or, if you use the map as actual map that returns new values, make the callback async, wrap the map call in `Promise.all` and await it

Answer (score 0):

One working solution is to split them up into two different maps

```js
const editorJSON = {
  1: "Startpoint",
  2: "Answer",
  3: "Question"
};
//console logged at end to show output order
const order = [];
//longer async
async function mockLonger(param) {
  return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(order.push(param)), 2000);
  })
}
//shorter async
async function mockShorter(param) {
  return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(order.push(param)), 1000);
  })
}
//async map 
async function mapArray(array) {
  console.log("processing...");
  const resultsA = array.map(async(key, index) => {
    if (editorJSON[key] === "Startpoint") await mockLonger("longer");
  })
  //process longer call first
  await Promise.all(resultsA)

  const resultsB = array.map(async(key, index) => {
    if (editorJSON[key] === "Question") await mockShorter("shorter");
  })
  //then shorter call
  await Promise.all(resultsB)
  console.log("Output Order:", order)
}

mapArray(Object.keys(editorJSON));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be within a map function? Just iterate the array and await.

```js
const editorJSON = {1: "Startpoint", 2: "Answer", 3: "Question"};

(async () => {
  for (const value of Object.values(editorJSON)) {
    await saveNodeasIntentinDialogflow(value);
  }
})();

async function saveNodeasIntentinDialogflow(name) {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000 * Math.random()));
  console.log(`${name} is done`);
}
```